# Values for which the $\max$ function is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Let the function $f$ be:
$$
f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \max (x, y):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x & \text { for } x \geq y \\
y & \text { for } x<y
\end{array}\right.
$$

I am now trying to prove for which values $f$ *is* differentiable. As I am finding many examples such as $\max(x,0)$ for which $f$ is *not* differentiable I am stuck finding an approach for the other way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is differentiable at $(x,y)$ iff $x \neq y$.

Comment: $\max \{x,o\}$ is continuous everwhere.

Comment: Suggestion: If $g(x, y) = x$, where is $g$ differentiable? Then, what bearing does this have on differentiability of $f$?